# Gatsby doesn't show pages already present in pages folder

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to access `http://localhost:8000/vidx?v=1614154126744` using

```
navigate(`/vidx?v=${u}`, {
      state: { vid: r },
      replace: true
    })
```

`vidx.js` is already present in pages folder. I am getting the following error. When I refresh, `/vidx` is visible.

[image: 404 error]

What am i doing wrong here?

I am moving CRA to gatsby.

Update: Adding trailing slash (please see the url in the attached screenshot) still gives the same error

```
navigate(`/vidx?v=${u}/`, {
      state: { vid: r },
      replace: true
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the trailing slash? ``navigate(`/vidx?v=${u}/`...`` In addition, can you share the code of the `vidx.js` page?

Comment: Yes, still getting the same error. Code - https://codepen.io/shrwtz/pen/jOVLgpK?editors=0010

Comment: Have you tried removing the `replace` ?

Comment: Yes same error.